# Put value in blogger post title by javascript

Tags: javascript, blogger

I'm trying to put a value with javascript code in the post title.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('K3JSBVB-C-b titleField')[0].value = 'Test';
```

But when i click publish the post go as : (Untitled post)
Any Help Please

post image [image]

Comment: A className can't have a space in it. Show the relevant html as in [mcve]

Comment: Even if i put just only the K3JSBVB-C it doesn't work

Comment: `value` is for inputs, you should try innerHTML instead

Comment: yes already tested

Comment: innerHtml,textContent nothing working

Answer (score 0):

The prop you have to set is `innerHTML` not `value` or `innerHtml`

```
document.getElementsByClassName('K3JSBVB-C-b titleField')[0].innerHTML = 'Test';
```

== EDIT ==

But since your target is an Input DOM element you want to set the `value` as @Musa said

```
document.getElementsByClassName('K3JSBVB-C-b titleField')[0].value = 'NEW AWSOME TITLE'
```

Comment: Show us the class of the DOM element with your Inspector tool ([for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/))

Comment: i think that the field is protected or something that this you need to click and put text manually

Comment: I've registered to Blogger and used `.value` property (since it's an Input as @Musa said) to set the title from JS and it works: 
https://imgur.com/RA9jqtU

Comment: try to hit publish the title will not appear in the list  https://imgur.com/a/YGAeH70

Comment: You can't change page content permanently using javascript console, only for testing and all your changes will disappear when you click a button or refresh page.

Comment: Yes i know but i request only to change the value of an input then click publish to send that value